# invalid number exception while reading csv using java

Tags: java, oracle, csv

i am reading csv file and storing into oracle database using java
my database structure is :

```
Name          Null Type          
------------- ---- ------------- 
DATE_D             VARCHAR2(800) 
DESCRIPTION        VARCHAR2(800) 
TRANSACTIONID      VARCHAR2(800) 
CREDIT_AMOUNT      NUMBER(8,2)   
DEBIT_AMOUNT       NUMBER(8,2)   
REMAINING          NUMBER(8,2)   
ODAMOUNT           NUMBER(8,2)   
ENTEREDBY          VARCHAR2(800) 
REMARKS            VARCHAR2(800)
```

till 300 records program inserting the records properly without exception
the 300th record is :

```
30/01/2017 17:36:19 ICCDMR AGENT COMMISSION OLKB9O  0.17    0   2744.63 0  INHYD03904375S   ICCDMR AGENT COMMISSION - 9550681786
```

301 record is this :

```
30/01/2017 17:33:49 ICCDMR AGENT COMMISSION OLKB24  0.08    0   2744.46 0   INHYD03904375S  ICCDMR AGENT COMMISSION - 7097545406
```

i am wondering that what is the deference here that i am getting invalid number exception.
here is my java code:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        linecount++;
        String[] value = line.split(",");
        if (linecount != 1) {
            value1 = value[0].split(" ");
            System.out.println(value1[0]);
            System.out.println(value1[1]);
            String sql = "insert into HARMS( date_d,time_t,Description ,TransactionId,"
                        + "Credit_Amount,Debit_Amount ,Remaining,OdAmount ,EnteredBy,Remarks)"
                        + "values('" + value1[0] + "','" + value1[1] + "','" + value[1] + "','" 
                        + value[2] + "','" + value[3] + "','" + value[4] + "','" + value[5] + "','" 
                        + value[6] + "','" + value[7] + "','" + value[8] + "')";
            ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            int c = ps.executeUpdate();
       }
}
```

please get me out of this.

Comment: The examples you show don't have comas, so they're not the original file. Also make sure you're not "off by one" line when looking at the input file for issues.

Comment: You did not quite understand the purpose of a prepared statement. Add the values as parameters.

Comment: Your insert statement does not match your table structure: column time_t does not exist.

Comment: Do not store date/times in `VARCHAR2` columns - Oracle has a `DATE` data type that will store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that `TIME_T is also VARCHAR2 column present in your table` but you have missed to write it in your question. Try below code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO HARMS(DATE_D, TIME_T, DESCRIPTION, TRANSACTIONID, CREDIT_AMOUNT, DEBIT_AMOUNT, REMAINING, ODAMOUNT, ENTEREDBY, REMARKS)"+
                " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, value1[0]);
ps.setString(2, value1[1]);
ps.setString(3, value[1]);
ps.setString(4, value[2]);
ps.setFloat(5, Float.parseFloat(value[3]));
ps.setFloat(6, Float.parseFloat(value[4]));
ps.setFloat(7, Float.parseFloat(value[5]));
ps.setFloat(8, Float.parseFloat(value[6]));
ps.setString(9, value[7]);
ps.setString(10, value[8]);
int c=ps.executeUpdate();
```